# What is the time to create a complement of a graph?

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

It seems to me that the running time to make a complement of a graph with $n$ nodes is $n!$. Is there any way to make this running time polynomial? That is, is there any method to construct a complement graph that has polynomial running time?

Comment: I should have said that the matrix had zeros along its diagonal. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to elaborate on @user35603's answer a little bit. Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix for a *simple graph* $G$. Then the adjacency matrix for $G$ complement can be easily constructed via:
$$
\mathbf{1} - A
$$
Where $\mathbf{1}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of all ones with zeros along its diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use *adjacency matrix* (it's $n \times n$).